# Display reputation decreases in the top-bar indicator

Tags: feature-request, reputation, notifications, top-bar

Generally, a reputation increase is indicated by a green indicator. Can there be an indicator for reputation decrease as well? This is because sometimes we don't know, when suddenly our reputation went down.

Comment: See also this feature request on MSE: [Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900/214632)